# Sending Input to process created using createprocess() in C on a windows machine

Tags: c, input, createprocess

**EDIT
I have found the solution to this problem.  The second input field in the createprocess() function call can be a string that is passed to the created processes argv[] in the main function.

Example:

```
CreateProcess("M:\\Projects\\Force\\Andrew\\force\\force.exe", "PASSME",NULL,NULL,FALSE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,NULL,NULL,&StartupInfo[i],&ProcessInfo[i]);
```

This will send "PASSME" as an input argument to the main function of the process that is being spawned.

Like the title says I am trying to write a program that sends information as inputs to other console applications.  The program I am writing launches 3 iterations of a program and sends a different input to each iteration.  The code I have so far:

```
PROCESS_INFORMATION ProcessInfo[3];
STARTUPINFO StartupInfo[3];
for(i=0;i<number;i++)
{
    ZeroMemory(&StartupInfo[i], sizeof(StartupInfo[i]));
    StartupInfo[i].cb = sizeof (StartupInfo[i]) ; //Only compulsory field
    CreateProcess("M:\\Projects\\Force\\Andrew\\force\\force.exe", NULL,NULL,NULL,FALSE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,NULL,NULL,&StartupInfo[i],&ProcessInfo[i]);

}


for(i=0;i<number;i++)
{
    WaitForSingleObject(ProcessInfo[i].hProcess,INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(ProcessInfo[i].hThread);
    CloseHandle(ProcessInfo[i].hProcess);
}
```

And so the force.exe program takes two input prompts one after another.  I am looking to send 2 different numbers to each of those two input prompts to each iteration of the process that is launched.

So I was wondering if what I described is possible, and what the best way to do that might be?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at the `hStdInput` field of the `STARTUPINFO` structure?

Comment: If you already have an answer to your question why not add it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT I have found the solution to this problem. The second input field in the createprocess() function call can be a string that is passed to the created processes argv[] in the main function.

Example:
    CreateProcess("M:\Projects\Force\Andrew\force\force.exe", "PASSME",NULL,NULL,FALSE,     CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,NULL,NULL,&StartupInfo[i],&ProcessInfo[i]);

This will send "PASSME" as an input argument to the main function of the process that is being spawned